# When I add "Index" action My layout Does not work

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core-mvc

I got an interesting problem . I am working with dotnetcore(3.1). So i got a layout page and i am using it in my pages. the interesting thing is;
when I run it on my Browser like this" https://localhost:44391/Home" it works well but when tried to type "https://localhost:44391/Home/Index" Program cannot reach my css and js links ıt comes without css only Html.

```
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
```

}

```html
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

```html
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
```

here is my Viewstart so ı normally use .netframework and doing this for a long time. first time on Core what am i missing ?

Comment: How is your CSS included? If it uses a relative path, then `/Home/Index` is a different directory than `/Home`

Comment: I use  a premade web template and added my css files into the wwwroot files than ı linked them like " ~/css/style.css..".

Comment: have you change default structure? is your index under any Area or using specific route?     add all your js, css file under wwwroot and refer from layout like "<script src="~/js/site.js" integrity="" asp-append-version="true"></script>"